# how to use php to save info

Tags: php, html

I am trying to follow along here in my book when building my website, I am trying to work on PHP/ .pl form saving, but I cannot seem to get it to work like it should.

```
<form action="/cgi-bin/contactlist.php" method="post">
<fieldset>
<legend>Join E-mail List Test blah blah</legend>
<p>This is a test and I am curious what it does so lol </p>
<ol>
<li>
<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
</li>
<li>
<label for="email">Email:</label>
<input type="text`enter code here`" name="email" id="email" />
</li>
</ol>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The code listed above, but the form is not saving like it should, any suggestions?

Comment: Where are you trying to save? What happens when you try to save? Add the PERL and PHP..

Comment: What is in the contents of the contactlist.php file?

Comment: first of all move the php file out of "cgi-bin" and are you save the content in DB or datafile ?

Comment: This HTML does not save anything, so you will need to show us `contactlist.php` script, which we assume probably will